# How to press TAB or ENTER key after inserting an input in ROBOT Framework

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

How do i press TAB key or ENTER key when i enter input text.
The action that i wish to do is

1. In the system , there is input field. when a user enters data as input text in that field and press TAB (when i enter input text the system gives suggestions of the name ... )The way i'm doing is

```
Input Text    xpath://input[@id='token-input-for_user']    test
Press Key    xpath://input[@id='token-input-for_user']    TAB
```

the above solution does not work as after entering input text it again clicks again on the same field.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
Press Keys    //input[@id='token-input-for_user']    test+TAB
```

Comment: can we add a delay or wait after entering test and before clicking tab... becasuse the script is quite fast press tab before the suggestion appears

Comment: Not with this keyword. What's going on in the app? Is it a network request you need to wait for before the suggestions appear?

Comment: yes ... until the suggestion appears, the user has to select the option from the below suggestions....